# Issues from Upgrading one version at a time?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

I've been using 12.04 since it came out, never changed due to stability, but I do fear that I am missing a lot of stuff and new software in the newest versions. My idea was to upgrade to 14.04 when it pops out, from lts to lts, but I feel that I can't wait. Is there any issue from upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10, 13.04 and then 13.10? I remember that when upgrading windows vista to seven, instead of doing a clean install of windows seven, would make the windows heavier on resources, and quite slow in general.

So, what are the risks of upgrading to the latest non lts release instead of doing a clean install? are there performance issues? loss of personal data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always a chance of something going wrong when doing an upgrade. And doing 3 upgrades in a row is just asking for trouble.

By doing a fresh install, you have far less risk of corrupting your install, you can start out with an optimized partitioning and get the "new install" feeling.

Just remember to backup your /home before doing anything. Upgrade or fresh install, make sure your data is safe!

Comment: The problem is that I use wine to run some apps and games, is there a way to back up files from the .wine folder? or other user definitions? and it's ok if I only update from 12.04 lts to 14.04 lts when it comes out?

Comment: you can always just copy out the contents of the wine directory. That will save your Wine settings and it all. When you backup, just remember to show hidden files in the directories (hotkeys CTRL+H). It is more than OK to wait for an LTS, if you are already on the next LTS. The versions in between LTS's are just if you want the new stuff now. :)

Comment: Thanks Dan :) So I do not need to do a clean install of the new lts, I can just upgrade, and ther wont be any problem right? its more dangerous if i do one version after version until i reach the next lts

Comment: When upgrading there is always a chance of problems. With most fresh installs it works the first time. Most. I'd wait for 14.04 to release in April before upgrading your system, since you are on an LTS anyway. And I recommend doing a fresh install of 14.04 instead of using the upgrade tool.